# How to position two thymeleaf elements next to each other

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

If the user is logged his name appears on top right of the screen. If the user hasn't validated his email a link appears with the message "email not validated". The link is to send email validation again. In the back everything is working fine. The link is positioned bellow the user name, now I am trying to position it next to the user name and to be in brackets.

```
<div th:if="${isLogged}" class="div-block-10">
    <div class="user_name" th:text="${user.getFirstName() + ' ' +
        user.getLastName()}">Your Name</div>
    <div th:if="${!user.isEmailValidated()}" class="div-block-13">
        <div class="email_confirmed">
            <a th:href="@{'/email/send/' + ${user.getToken()}}">Your email is
                not confirmed!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.div-block-10 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.div-block-13{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 7px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I tried to change the `div-block-13` css but I cant figure out how to position the link to appear right next to the user name. I guess there is a way to put the link together with the username in the `div-block-10` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below CSS:

```
.div-block-13{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 7px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It is not working as intended. I want to move the link to be next to the user name if he hasn't validated email. Now its bellow the username. Even if I change the div-block-13 to have same margins as div-block-10 it is not appearing next to the username but under it. I know there is span property in css but I cant figure out how to put the whole Thymeleaf code in div-block-10 element

Comment: The <span> tags also generally won't help with the line breaks. Might have to try the CSS approach only.